# Facebook post object

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-ads-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.2

I'm using Facebook Ads API. And receive AdCreative's property object_story_id in form %PageID%_%PostID%.
Then I can get two obects from FB API:

- the first using that URI: https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/%PostID%
- the second using https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/%PageID%_%PostID%

So here I have several qusetions:
Why there are two different objects, don't they represent the same logical structure?
Why sometimes I can access the first one, but can't - the second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't attempt to infer meaning from the value of `id`

Though the format of some IDs is currently the post ID appended with '_' another identifier, that's not a given, and neither part of that exploded token can be assumed to be a valid object

The `id` should be treated as strictly an opaque identifier - if you're given an `id` which isn't usable in a subsequent call where it should be usable per the documentation, that's likely a bug

Comment: Thanks. That was a bug indeed. It's described here:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/311567308967873/